# AS3-Flash CS6 How to make a code that applies to all objects

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Right, I am trying to make a game and I would like a bit of code that whenever I place makes something applies to all objects. For example I have: A background, Lamp, Player and Text. I would like it so I don't have to make the Lamp, Background and Text a symbol but have one bit of code that refers to them whenever I type it, so I don't have to list them all individually.

Comment: I think this question is too broad. Your example is also confusing to me. Can you explain more what you are trying to do? Show an example of the code you currently have and how you want to improve it?

Comment: You can iterate through the DisplayObjectContainer for the stage / symbol see - http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html and then potentially pass the relevant child through as a function param...!? - hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to affect a specific, known set of display objects, you could add them into an array when they get created, and then use that array as your collection of objects to do whatever you need to.

Code here is procedural, not OOP, but should give you the gist. If you paste this into an FLA file and create the three objects (instances names) you'll have a decent sample of what this approach may be able to help you work with.

This can become more advanced, creates asa its own AS3 class, and be made smarted to handle whatever visual display changes that might be needed. But you only need ot make it as complicated as suits your needs.

```
var myDisplayObjs_arr:Array = [];

function addObj(obj:DisplayObject):void{
    myDisplayObjs_arr.push(obj);
}

function affectObjs(config:Object):void{
    // config object that includes things like alpha, colorTransform, whatever
    for (var i:int = 0; i<myDisplayObjs_arr.length; i++){
        var dispObj:DisplayObject = myDisplayObjs_arr[i];
        if (config.alpha) {
            dispObj.alpha = config.alpha;
        }
        if (config.scaleX) {
            dispObj.scaleX = config.scaleX;
        }
    }
}

addObj(lamp);
addObj(background);
addObj(header_txt);

// Call affectObjs(), passing it an object of some basic changes
affectObjs({alpha:.5, scaleX:2});
```